# Storing inorder traversal of tree C

Tags: c, binary-tree

How do we store the elements of tree in an array using inorder traversal ?
I read people saying store parent index at i and left child 2*i+1 and right ar 2*i+2 .But it does not work for me ? 
Help needed :)

Comment: Please post your code for more help.

Comment: The technique outlined works if the root node is at index 1, not 0 as is customary in C.  The simplest system is simply to allocate an extra entry and not use the 0 entry.  Thus, the root is at 1, its two children are at 2 and 3; the children of 2 are at 4 and 5; the children of 3 are at 6 and 7, and so on.  Whether this is what you're looking for is a different matter; an inorder traversal is different.

Comment: I got it My code is working fine now :) 
Anyways thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Supposing it is a binary tree, here is a pseudocode

```
tree_to_array(tree, array, index)
    if tree != NULL then
        // stores recursively all the elements on the left
        index = tree_to_array(tree.left, array, index)
        // the root of the (sub)tree
        array[index] = tree
        // stores recursively all the elements on the right
        return tree_to_array(tree.right, array, index + 1)
    return index
```